# SQL how to get dynamically determined array entry with string_to_array on a delimited string

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Suppose I have a table with the format

`user, code, source`

with sample data:

```
p1, a-b-c-d, g1
p2, b-c-d, g1
p4, q-a-b-c-d, g2
p5, b-e-d, g3
p6, q-a-c-d, g2
p7, c-d, g3
p3, a-b-a-a-d-e, g2
p8, a-b-a-a-d-e, g2
```

I want to write a query where I select all users who have a letter 'b' in their code, and then group by the letter that immediately follows it.

For example the output on the above should be:

```
count, group

3,c
1,e
2,a
```

To be clear there will always be a letter that follows 'b' if it exists.

Right now my query looks like:

```
select count(a.user), (string_to_array(a.code,'-'))[2]
from [table] a
where a.code LIKE 'b'
group by 2
```

But clearly this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `unnest with ORDINALITY` and `LEAD` to get next value, then simple `GROUP BY`:

```
CREATE TABLE t
AS
SELECT 'p1' "user", 'a-b-c-d' code, 'g1' source
UNION ALL SELECT'p2', 'b-c-d', 'g1'
UNION ALL SELECT'p4', 'q-a-b-c-d', 'g2'
UNION ALL SELECT'p5', 'b-e-d', 'g3'
UNION ALL SELECT'p6', 'q-a-c-d', 'g2'
UNION ALL SELECT'p7', 'c-d', 'g3'
UNION ALL SELECT'p3', 'a-b-a-a-d-e', 'g2'
UNION ALL SELECT'p8', 'a-b-a-a-d-e', 'g2';
```

Query:

```
WITH cte AS (
  select  * , LEAD(elem) OVER(PARTITION BY "user", code, source ORDER BY nr) grp
  from t a
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL unnest(string_to_array(a.code,'-')) 
          WITH ORDINALITY AS s(elem, nr) ON TRUE
)
SELECT grp, COUNT(*)
FROM cte
WHERE elem = 'b'
GROUP BY grp;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=672b701d889082ecaaf707836d01b765)**